# How can I fix the error here in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have used students as a dictionary. But when I try to match the input string with the dictionary value (which is also a string) it shows

```py
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

What's problem with this code?

```
students = {
    "Male":["Jones",162,21],
    "Female":["Sarah",162,18]
    }
print(type(students))
for students in students.keys():
    gen = input("What's your gender?: ").strip().capitalize()
    if gen in students:
        name =input("What's your name?: ").strip().capitalize()
        if name == students[gen][0]:
            print("Your name is {}").format(name)
```

Comment: `for students in students.keys():` is dangerous (if not completely wrong), since both the loop variable and the dict have the same name. Which is probably the cause of your error.

Comment: Hey @travel, in the future try making your titles more specific. A good one for this question would be "How to fix TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Answer (score 0):

2 **typo** in your code. 
try this:

```
students = {
    "Male":["Jones",162,21],
    "Female":["Sarah",162,18]
    }
print(type(students))
for index in students.keys():
    gen = input("What's your gender?: ").strip().capitalize()
    if gen in students.keys():
        name =input("What's your name?: ").strip().capitalize()
        if name == students[gen][0]:
            print("Your name is {}".format(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what your code should look like:

```
for student in students.keys():
    gen = input("What's your gender?: ").strip().capitalize()
    if gen in students.keys():
        name =input("What's your name?: ").strip().capitalize()
        if name == students[gen][0]:
            print("Your name is {}").format(name)
```

your issue was that you named the variable and the dict the same.

Answer (score 0):

This version worked for me:

```
students = {
"Male": ["Jones", 162, 21],
"Female": ["Sarah", 162, 18]
}
for student in students.keys():
    gen = input("What's your gender?: ").strip().capitalize()
    if gen in student:
        name = input("What's your name?: ").strip().capitalize()
        if name == students[gen][0]:
            print(f"Your name is {name}")
```